# Нужна ли запятая после "следующего года"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Её хорошо сеять в начале июня, тогда цветок зацветёт в июле-августе следующего года и цветение будет длиться месяц.

Answer (score 2):

Однако спорная ситуация...

1. Не нужна:

*цветок зацветёт* и *цветение будет длиться* объединены общим словом *тогда*.

2. Нужна,

если предположить, что *тогда* вовсе не общее у двух основ, а *цветение будет длиться месяц* при любом раскладе - без строгой привязки к началу июня.